# Converting a 3D array to a 3D model

Tags: java, 3d, terrain, voxel

I'm trying to find a type of software that I could use to convert a 3D Java array to a 3D voxel model. I'm developing a voxel terrain generator in Java and I need some way to visualize the 3-dimensional integer arrays. What software (or APIs) would be good for this purpose?

Also, the array I'm trying to convert is a 3D array of integers where each integer should correspond to a voxel with a specific color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are going to define your terrain surface as a surface of constant value in your voxel value array. You can polygonalize this surface with a method like Marching Cubes. Adding controls to rotate the data set and move the contour level up or down makes it possible to visualize the whole data set.